# Specializing a Protocol where Self is a Generic Class

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

Say I have the following `Swift` classes:

```swift
class Foo {}
class Bar<T: Foo> {}
```

and this protocol:

```swift
protocol Zip {}
```

I am trying to create another protocol `Zap` that specializes itself where `Self` is `Bar`, but I want to further require that Bar's generic type be an instance of `Foo` that implements `Zip`.

```swift
protocol Zap where Self: Bar<Foo & Zip> {}
```

This results in an error stating that both `Foo` and `Zip` must inherit from `Foo`.

Is there a way to do this using Swift generics?

Thanks in advance for the assistance.

---

**Edit - Intended Usage:**

I apologize if this is confusing, but hopefully it shows what I'm trying to do.

Say `Bar` has a reference to the instance of `Foo`, protocol `Zip` has a function `diddle` and `Zap` has a function `daddle`:

```swift
class Bar<T: Foo> {
  var foo: T
}

protocol Zip {
  func diddle()
}

protocol Zap {
  func daddle()
}
```

What I am trying to do is provide a default implementation in an extension of `Zap` to call the function `diddle()` when `daddle()` is called from `Bar`

```swift
extension Zap where Self: Bar<Foo & Zip> {
  func daddle(){
    foo.diddle()
  }
}
```

In the end this may just be bad architecture.

Thanks for the responses.

---

**Edit - Possible Solution**

This seems to compile and may work for what I'm trying to do.

```swift
class Foo {}

class Bar<T: Foo> {
    var foo: T

    init(foo: T) {
        self.foo = foo
    }
}

class FooZip: Foo, Zip {
    func diddle() {}
}

protocol Zip {
    func diddle()
}

protocol Zap where Self: Bar<FooZip> {}

extension Zap where Self: Bar<FooZip> {
    func daddle() {
        foo.diddle()
    }
}
```

Thank you @kiril-s and those of you who commented.

Comment: It's not a problem with generics per se, it's problem with `Foo & Zip` not being subclass of `Foo`

Comment: Sadly that is not possible. You cannot create a generic type restriction like that, since you'd need to provide an extract specialised version of the generic type `Self`. If you only want to specialise some specific generic functions inside the `Zap` protocol, that is possible though.

Comment: The design seems a little bit odd, can you tell us what you want to achieve with it? Maybe we can find another solution. Otherwise we might be running into an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: I added more information to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing any other details. If the goal is that Zap only accepts `Bar` of type that inherits `Foo` and conforms to `Zip` ... how about something like this:

```
extension Foo: Zip {}
protocol Zap where Self: Bar<Foo> {}
```

or

```
class FooZip: Foo, Zip {}
protocol Zap where Self: Bar<FooZip> {}
```

Comment: The second part of this may work for my intended purposes. Thank you.